# Excel, how to return a specific row from a data set

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Data set has 25 rows and 95 columns with different numbers in them, how do I find out what row a specific number is on
Example:

```
   A       B       C      D     E     ...
1 Title   1234   2134   3124   4123
2 Title   4321   3214   2413   1432 
3 Title   2314   4132   3421   1423
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use AGGREGATE:

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($B$1:$E$3)/($B$1:$E$3=G2),1)
```

[image]

---

If you do not have Excel 2010 or later then use this Array Formula:

```
=MIN(IF($B$1:$E$3=G2,ROW($B$1:$E$3)))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Needed to return the title, so I used =INDEX and =AGGREGATE.

Comment: @coffeepls please come back in a couple minutes and mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.